# Oracle - Query address from multiple Column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to query a Staff's addresses (Home and Correspondence Address).

What I have for Staff table is

```
Staff_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Home_Adress, Corr_Address
```

And for Address table is

```
Address_ID, Line1, Line2, Line3, Post_Code
```

Both the addresses are linked to the Address_ID. I've read around the site, it seems the approach for this is Union or Join, which I'm not really sure how to write it down.

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Home_Adress, Corr_Address FROM STAFF
UNION
SELECT Address_ID FROM ADDRESS
GROUP BY First_Name
```

Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the table `Address` two times, one to get the `HomeAddress` and another one to get the `Corr_Address`:

```
SELECT
  s.First_Name,
  s.Last_Name,
  ah.Line1     AS HomeLine1,
  ah.Line2     AS HomeLine2,
  ah.Line3     AS HomeLine3,
  ah.Post_Code AS HomePost_Code,
  ac.Line1     AS CorrLine1,
  ac.Line2     AS CorrLine2,
  ac.Line3     AS CorrLine3,
  ac.Post_Code AS corrPostCode
FROM Staff AS s
INNER JOIN address AS ah ON s.Home_Address = ah.address_ID
INNER JOIN address AS ac ON s.corr_address = ac.addressid;
```

---

### **Update:**

If you want to combine the addresses' details for each address in one field, you can do this:

```
SELECT
  s."First_Name",
  s."Last_Name",
  ah."Line1" || ', ' || ah."Line2" || ', ' || ah."Line3" || ', ' || ah."Post_Code" AS HomeAddress,
  ac."Line1" || ', ' || ac."Line2" || ', ' || ac."Line3" || ', ' || ac."Post_Code" AS CorrAddress
FROM Staff s
INNER JOIN address ah ON s."Home_Adress" = ah."Address_ID"
INNER JOIN address ac ON s."Corr_Address" = ac."Address_ID";
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7005a/8)

This will give you something like this:

```
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |                   HOMEADDRESS |                   CORRADDRESS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        foo |       bar | line11, line12, line13, 34222 |   line12, line22, line32, 653 |
|       foo2 |      bar2 | line13, line23, line33, 34545 | line14, line25, line35, 33452 |
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, get back to you soon. By the look of it, this seems to what I needed.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to show the addresses as Home Address and Corresponding Address in one field each (Combine the Line1 Line 2, Line3, and Postcode into one field)?

Comment: @user1433571 - Is it ***only*** one address record from `Address` table for each user in `Staff` table?

Comment: Each Staff has two records in the Address table. (eg. Staff ID = 3 has the Address ID = 10 for Home and Address_ID = 23 for Correspondence) Is that what you meant?

Comment: Syukran! It would perfectly :)